# How do I use the async .update() method for DataTables in MDBootstrap?

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, mdbootstrap

I am new to MDBootstrap and I am trying to learn how to use the DataTables. I have seen the examples on their website for Async table updates, however I found it confusing to convert it to my use case.

I am interested in learning how to use the async table update method specifically since I would like my table to update four columns dynamically based on filters that I am collecting from Dropdowns.

I would like the table to get its data by calling a PHP endpoint that will return data back in JSON and I am not understanding how to use the `asyncTable.update()` method (based on their example).

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume the PHP endpoint returns JSON that looks similar to this:

`[ { "a": "a string", "b": "another string", "c": "another string", "d": "another string" }, { "a": "a string", "b": "another string", "c": "another string", "d": "another string" }]`

Based on the example code snippet from the MDBootstrap site (listed below), how do I modify the code to call my own endpoint? I do not understand the javascript syntax within the `.update()` method of the example code:

```
const columns = [
  { label: 'A', field: 'a' },
  { label: 'B', field: 'b' },
  { label: 'C', field: 'c' },
  { label: 'D', field: 'd' },
];

const asyncTable = new mdb.Datatable(
  document.getElementById('datatable'),
  {
    columns,
  }
);

//var url = 'MY OWN PHP ENDPOINT URL';
var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    asyncTable.update(
      {
        rows: data.map((user) => ({
          ...user,
          address: `${user.address.city}, ${user.address.street}`,
          company: user.company.name,
        })),
      },
      { loading: false }
    );
  });
});
```

I would appreciate any help on how to use this method using my own end point and not the example endpoint and data structure presented.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change link in `fetch` for your endpoint's URL

```
  fetch('https://custom-api.com/rows')
```

The update() method takes two parameters: `data` and `options`. Upon changing the URL you have to modify the `data` parameter to correspond to your data. In your example it will look like:

```
   fetch('https://your-url.com/rows')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    asyncTable.update(
      {
        rows: data.map((row) => ({
          a: row.a,
          b: row.b,
          c: row.c,
          d: row.d
        })),
      },
      { loading: false }
    );
  });
```

this example might look cleaner for you: https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/standard/m-duszak/3000204#js-tab-view